# Collecting only a specific value and selecting as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have something like this as a select_tag :

`<p><%= setting_select :ui_theme, My::Themes.themes.collect {|t| [t.name, t.id]}, :blank => :label_default, :label => :label_theme %></p>`

Rite now it is collecting all the values and displaying but I want to collect only a specific value and make it default. This value has name = "Test".

Thus it should look like this and it should be default:

`<option selected="selected" value="Test">Test</option>`

Note : Here setting_select is a helper which is defined like this:

```
def setting_select(setting, choices, options={})
    if blank_text = options.delete(:blank)
      choices = [[blank_text.is_a?(Symbol) ? l(blank_text) : blank_text, '']] + choices
    end
    setting_label(setting, options).html_safe +
      select_tag("settings[#{setting}]",
                 options_for_select(choices, Setting.send(setting).to_s),
                 options).html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options_for_select` allows you to pre-select an option by passing its value. Example:

```
<%= options_for_select([['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2], ...], 2) %>
```

output:

```
<option value="1">Lisbon</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Madrid</option>
```

More information about [select tag and options_for_select](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags).

Comment: But how do I collect it as it is in my case. Thanks in advance

Comment: `code<select id="settings_ui_theme" name="settings[ui_theme]">
<option value="">Default</option>
<option value="alternate">Alternate</option>
<option value="classic">Classic</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Test">Test</option>
</select>`code`

This is what I am collecting rite now. How Do I collect only Test and make it selected. 

Thanks :)